# Kotlin cloneable vs deep copy

Tags: android, kotlin, copy, deep-copy, cloneable

I implemented various times copy and deep copy. Didn't use clone a lot so decided to investigate it. I have class:

```
data class CountryResponse(var data: List<CountryData>): Cloneable {

public override fun clone(): Any {
    return super.clone()
}

override fun toString(): String {
    return "CountryResponse(data='$data')"
}
}
```

As you can see I already implemented `Cloneable`. In my code I do:

```
var test = (CountryResponse(
        listOf(
            CountryData(null, nation = "", year = 3, population = 4),
            CountryData(null, nation = "", year = 3, population = 3)
        )
    ))

    var copyOfTest = test.clone()
```

After this I debug. In my debugger copyOfTest and test have different references. So shallow copy is done. But when I try to check references for "data" they are same. This means that deep copy is not done.

(I implemented `Cloneable` also in `CountryData` data class).

How to achieve deep copy with cloneable? Also what is preferrable/better to use, are there any advantages. If `Cloneable` has so much code, implementing it in data classes, etc, it looks easier for me to do deep copy and not bother with cloneable ever again:

```
   var copyOfTest = test.copy(data = test.data.map { it.copy() })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object#clone`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) is supposed to be a shallow copy. It just creates a new object of the same type with the *same* (reference equality) fields

If you want to create a deep clone using that method, you need to add custom logic, e.g.:

```kotlin
public override fun clone(): Any {
    val ret = super.clone()
    ret.data = ArrayList(ret.data)
    return ret
}
```

Comment: oh I see. But if I need to define all logic by myself than It really looks like longer version of deep copy implementation, doesn't it :D

Comment: Well, if the types of your attributes already provide a `clone()` method, you might be able to reuse those.